# Simple language identification using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, functional-programming, nlp

I'm experimenting with LINQ for the first time and decided to try basic human language identification. The input text gets tested against `HashSet`s of the most common 10,000 words in the language and receives a score.

My question is, is there a better approach to the LINQ query? Maybe the other form that I don't know? It works, but I'm sure that the experts here will be able to provide a much cleaner solution!

```
public PolyAnalyzer() {
    Dictionaries = new Dictionary<string, AbstractDictionary>();
    Dictionaries.Add("Bulgarian", new BulgarianDictionary());
    Dictionaries.Add("English", new EnglishDictionary());
    Dictionaries.Add("German", new GermanDictionary());
    Dictionaries.Values.Select(n => new Thread(() => n.LoadDictionaryAsync())).ToList().ForEach(n => n.Start());            
}  

public string getResults(string text) {
    int total = 0;
    return string.Join(" ",
        Dictionaries.Select(n => new {
            Language = n.Key,
            Score = new Regex(@"\W+").Split(text).AsQueryable().Select(m => n.Value.getScore(m)).Sum()
        }).
        Select(n => { total += n.Score; return n; }).
        ToList().AsQueryable(). // Force immediate evaluation
        Select(n =>
        "[" + n.Score * 100 / total + "% " + n.Language + "]").
        ToArray());
}
```

P.S. I'm aware that this is an extremely simplistic approach to language identification, I'm just interested in the LINQ side of things.

Comment: Belongs on codereview.SE, no SO. Btw., language detection on character-level n-grams tends to be more reliable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would refactor it like this:

```
    public string GetResults(string text)
    {
        Regex wordRegex = new Regex(@"\W+");
        var scores = Dictionaries.Select(n => new
            {
                Language = n.Key,
                Score = wordRegex.Split(text)
                                 .Select(m => n.Value.getScore(m))
                                 .Sum()
            });

        int total = scores.Sum(n => n.Score);
        return string.Join(" ",scores.Select(n => "[" + n.Score * 100 / total + "% " + n.Language + "]");
    }
```

A few points:

1. The `AsQueryAble()` are unnecessary -
   this is all Linq to Objects, which
   is `IEnumerable<T>` - good enough.
2. Removed a few `ToList()` - also
   unnecessary and avoids eager loading
   of results when not needed.
3. While its nice having just one LINQ
   query **it's not a competition** - aim
   for readability overall and think about how
   you (and others) have to maintain the code. I split up your query into three more readable (imo) parts.
4. **Avoid side effects** by all means
   possible - I removed the one you had
   to the variable `total` - it's
   confusing - LINQ queries shouldn't
   have side effects, because running the same query twice might yield different results. In your case you can just calculate the total in a separate Linq query.
5. **Don't re-new or re-calculate variables inside a Linq
   projection if not necessary** - I
   removed the regex from the Linq
   query and initialized the variable
   once outside - otherwise you are
   re-newing the Regex instance `N` times
   instead of just once. This might have huge performance implications depending on the query.

Comment: Indeed I can remove the `AsQueryable`s! Thanks for the notes, I'll keep them in mind (especially the bit about the side effects).

Comment: Accepting for the improvement of the code while keeping the functionality. Thanks for the tips :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the code you posted is very confusing. I've rewritten it and I think it gives you the same result (of course I couldn't test it and actually I think you're code has some wrong parts to it) but it should be much more concise now. Let me know if this is incorrect.

```
public PolyAnalyzer()
{
    Dictionaries = new Dictionary<string, AbstractDictionary>();
    Dictionaries.Add("Bulgarian", new BulgarianDictionary());
    Dictionaries.Add("English", new EnglishDictionary());
    Dictionaries.Add("German", new GermanDictionary());

    //Tip: Use the Parallel library to to multi-core, multi-threaded work.
    Parallel.ForEach(Dictionaries.Values, d =>
    {
        d.LoadDictionaryAsync();
    });            
}  

public Dictionary<string, int> GetResults(string text)
{
    //1) Split the words.
    //2) Calculate the score per dictionary (per language).
    //3) Return the scores.
    string[] words = new Regex(@"\w+").Split().ToArray();
    Dictionary<string, int> scores = this.Dictionaries.Select(d => new
    {
        Language = d.Key,
        Score = words.Sum(w => d.Value.GetScore(w))
    }));

    return scores;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the bit about `words.Sum`, that's much better than in my solution!

Comment: You're welcome. And to add to this, you shouldn't "do stuff" inside of `Select`. You should only be selecting things within there. (E.g., don't calculate the total in there.) I hope this example is clear enough and works for you.

Comment: Is there any other way to execute something for each element?

Comment: Sure: `elements.ForEach(e => DoSomethingWith(e))`

Comment: Doesn't work... works only with `List` at least with .NET 3.5 (I have Visual Studio 2008 only) and I believe it doesn't return back `e`.

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work?" If you're trying to simply for-each over the items then use `.ForEach`. If you want to "get a new representation of the items" then use `.Select`.